# C++: Why can't I convert a string to C-string with an initializer char foo[]?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
const char readArr[] = readWord.c_str();
```

This gives an error: array initializer must be an initializer list or string literal

Why must I use

```
const char *readArr = readWord.c_str();?
```

Comment: Well, because `c_str()` is a `const char*`. Furthermore, arrays are constant size, while `readWord` could be any size. Last, even if it were fixed-size what would it mean to initialize a `T[]` from a `T*`?

Comment: Yes, but I thought the compiler knew how big the word is. For example: char var[] = "hello"; would work correctly

Comment: @Goldname a vector has an arbitrary length. The compiler needs to know how long stack-allocated arrays are at compile time.

Comment: @Goldname: Firstly, in `char var[] = "hello";` case the compiler can immediately see how long the string is. In `c_str()` case it is not possible. Secondly, `char var[] = "hello";` is an exceptional situation, which is given special treatment by the language. Aside from that exceptional context, naked arrays are not copyable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for the same reason you can't

```
const char *p="foo";

const char readArr[]=p;
```

either. An array is not a discrete object that can be initialized. The only thing that can be initialized in C++ is a discrete object, and an array is not an object per se. An array is a conceptual address of a contiguous list of values, in consecutive memory locations. When an array is used in an expression, such as:

```
readArr[i]
```

The array's name decays to a pointer to the first element in the array. Now, guess what you did when you wrote this:

```
const char *readArr = readWord.c_str();
```

Well, you just stored a pointer to the first element in an array of characters, that's owned by the `readWord` `std::string`.

In a regular array declaration:

```
char readArr[]="Hello";
```

the compiler is given the length of the string, and thus it initialize a consecutive list of character values, and the label `readArr` to it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that arrays don't always decay to pointers, e.g. `void f(char(&arr)[N])`.

Answer (score 1):

`const char readArr[] = readWord.c_str();`

The reason this is not legal is that it simply doesn't make sense to initialise an array from a pointer. A pointer is in essence a memory address: it points to some data, whether that data is dynamically or statically allocated (allocated 'on the heap' or 'on the stack' respectively). A pointer does not record how much memory is there.

This is confusing to newcomers to C and C++ because the language often allows you to treat arrays as if they were just pointers to their first element. That doesn't mean that arrays *are* just pointers to their first element. They aren't. But if you use them in an expression they will *decay* to a pointer to their first element.

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays are not pointers. An array... is an array, period. `char readArr[]` (just like `char arr[4]`) declares something directly in the local memory space (the stack, for a function) so that something has to be statically allocated.

str.c_str() is somewhere on the heap so that can't work.

Comment: It's entirely possible to copy something from the heap to the stack. The issue is not where the string is but that the length of the string is unknown at compile time.

Comment: Obviously right; but that would be a copy, and I don't think that's what the question was about. Also the facts that str.c_str() has to point to the heap and that it's dynamically sized are the two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Nevertheless the issue here has nothing to do with the heap and the stack: it's about the distinction between arrays and pointers.

Comment: These issues are very much linked to me: understanding arrays is a big step in understanding the memory layout associated with a given code.

Comment: I have to agree with @MilesRout it's nothing to do with heap or stack. It just happen to be coincidental that dynamic arrays can only exist on the heap. The real problem is not being able to initialize an array from a pointer. If it was about heap/stack then you might think this was legal: `char a[] = ""; char b[] = a;`, but it's not because `a` has decayed to a pointer (because it is being used in an expression).

Comment: The compiler will complain about the decay but the fundamental reason is that arrays don't have copy constructors. Arrays are not pointers -- because arrays are more or less the same thing as std::array: a chuck of memory, that has a priori no reason other than convenience to decay to its address. And it is definitely not coincidental that objects on the stack must be statically sized; it is just essential that the size of the stack hasto be predictable, just like `sizeof (Class)` must also be constant.